# Can't open mdb in designer mode

Tags: microsoft-access, mdb

I'm working on a new tool in C#, which should replace the old Access tool they are using. To make sure I get all the validations in the tool right, I want to look in the current tool.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to open the tool. I've read that you could access the designer mode by holding the <kbd>shift</kbd> button, yet this doesn't work for me either (yes I held the <kbd>shift</kbd> button down until the application was fully loaded.

When I do hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> button down, I'll quickly see the ribbon I need, but it will disappear again.

So how can I access the designer mode, any suggestions?

Comment: You tried Shift + Enter?

Comment: Just tried it, still no Ribbon

Comment: what version of access are you trying?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I'm working on a secure office. I could open the file and it would show me the tool without the Ribbon, but to use the Ribbon I would of needed to install Access on this device. So installing Access solved the problem!